# created jar file throws NoClassDefFoundError while executing it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

My project looks something like this

```
maven-simple

    src/main/java         
    src/main/resources
    src/test/java
        -com.org.central
          -CommonMethods.java
    src/test/resources

    pom.xml
```

I am trying to create a jar file through this method in eclipse for the above project

1. Right Click -> Export -> Java -> Jar File
2. click Next -> Next -> Finish

exported jar file has been created in the path . 
Then i am importing this jar file in some other project(for ex:- project b) to use the CommonMethods.java

But i am getting this error

```
 ←[31mjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/org/central/CommonMethods
 at stepDefinitions.Check.iSeeElement(Check.java:14)    
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.org.central.CommonMethods
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at stepDefinitions.Check.iSeeElement(Check.java:14)
```

what have i done wrong ?

Comment: You should really take a look to Maven documentations : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/maven/topics & http://maven.apache.org/index.html

Comment: You need to include your dependencies in your classpath. Make a jar with dependencies (linked question) or use a custom classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar must contain `.class` files, not only `.java` files.

Run a `mvn clean install`, and you'll get your jar containing the classes.

BTW, always (**A L W A Y S**), start your class names with uppercase letters.

Comment: "not only .java files.", should we need java files?

Comment: It's not rare that you include sources in a jar, though not necessary for it to work.

Comment: i have done that , but still getting this error while running- package com.org.central does not exist. I can able to import CommonMethods without any error in eclipse .